# Function to return List of Map while iterating over String, kmer count

Tags: scala

I am working on creating a k-mer frequency counter (similar to word count in Hadoop) written in Scala. I'm fairly new to Scala, but I have some programming experience.

The input is a text file containing a gene sequence and my task is to get the frequency of each k-mer where `k` is some specified length of the sequence.

Therefore, the sequence `AGCTTTC` has three **5-mers** (AGCTT, GCTTT, CTTTC)

I've parsed through the input and created a huge string which is the entire sequence, the new lines throw off the k-mer counting as the end of one line's sequence should still form a k-mer with the beginning of the next line's sequence.

Now I am trying to write a function that will generate a list of maps `List[Map[String, Int]]` with which it should be easy to use scala's `groupBy` function to get the count of the common k-mers

```
import scala.io.Source

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Get all of the lines from the input file
    val input = Source.fromFile("input.txt").getLines.toArray

    // Create one huge string which contains all the lines but the first
    val lines = input.tail.mkString.replace("\n","")

    val mappedKmers: List[Map[String,Int]] = getMappedKmers(5, lines)

  }

  def getMappedKmers(k: Int, seq: String): List[Map[String, Int]] = {
    for (i <- 0 until seq.length - k) {
      Map(seq.substring(i, i+k), 1) // Map the k-mer to a count of 1
    }
  }
}
```

Couple of questions:

- How to create/generate `List[Map[String,Int]]`?
- How would you do it?

Any help and/or advice is definitely appreciated!

Comment: Why do you map every kmer with `1`? It looks able to be just a kmer, therefore the returned type can be just `List[String]`. So my suggested code is simply `seq sliding k toList`.

Comment: Good point, I was actually trying to do something like that just a minute ago. The `1` was there because I was attempting to adapt this bit of code to how word count works in a hadoop MapReduce job where each key gets mapped with a value of 1, and the reduce function accumulates totals for each key (kmer in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close—there are three fairly minor problems with your code.

The first is that `for (i <- whatever) foo(i)` is syntactic sugar for `whatever.foreach(i => foo(i))`, which means you're not actually doing anything with the contents of `whatever`. What you want is `for (i <- whatever) yield foo(i)`, which is sugar for `whatever.map(i => foo(i))` and returns the transformed collection.

The second issue is that `0 until seq.length - k` is a `Range`, not a `List`, so even once you've added the `yield`, the result still won't line up with the declared return type.

The third issue is that `Map(k, v)` tries to create a map with two key-value pairs, `k` and `v`. You want `Map(k -> v)` or `Map((k, v))`, either of which is explicit about the fact that you have a single argument pair.

So the following should work:

```
def getMappedKmers(k: Int, seq: String): IndexedSeq[Map[String, Int]] = {
  for (i <- 0 until seq.length - k) yield {
    Map(seq.substring(i, i + k) -> 1) // Map the k-mer to a count of 1
  }
}
```

You could also convert either the range or the entire result to a list with `.toList` if you'd prefer a list at the end.

It's worth noting, by the way, that the `sliding` method on `Seq` does exactly what you want:

```
scala> "AGCTTTC".sliding(5).foreach(println)
AGCTT
GCTTT
CTTTC
```

I'd definitely suggest something like `"AGCTTTC".sliding(5).toList.groupBy(identity)` for real code.